# Passing Data Between Viewmodels MvvmCross

Tags: android, xamarin, viewmodel, mvvmcross

I am working on Xamarin Android Application and I am using MvvmCross.I am not able to pass and retrieve data between Viewmodels.
What is the solution ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That depends on what data you want to retrieve. For objects look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10659405/2653134) from Stuart.

And when you want to send/retrieve non-object data, you can do that with the [build in viewmodel-navigation](https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/wiki/ViewModel--to-ViewModel-navigation) like following example:

```
// Navigate to viewmodel with parameters
var param = new Dictionary<string, string>
{
    {"key1", "value for key 1"
    {"key2", 12}
};

ShowViewModel<MyViewModel>(param);
```

And then retrieve the Parameters in your `MyViewModel`:

```
protected override void InitFromBundle(IMvxBundle parameters)
{
    if (parameters.Data.ContainsKey("key1"))
    {
        var mykey1value = parameters.Data["key1"]
    }

    // And so on

    base.InitFromBundle(parameters);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

With MvvmCross 5 you can use `IMvxNavigationService`

For example, you have `FooViewModel` and `BarViewModel`

```
public class FooViewModel : MvxViewModel {}
public class BarViewModel : MvxViewModel<DataParameter> {}
```

and you want to pass some data from FooVM to BarVM.
As you can see BarViewModel inherits from MvxViewModel with DataParameter as a generic type. This class describes data that we want to throw to BarViewModel.

```
public class DataParameter
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Now you can use `IMvxNavigationService` in `FooViewModel` like that:

```
var parameter = new DataParameter
{
    Name = "Alex"
};

await Mvx
   .IoCProvider
   .Resolve<IMvxNavigationService>
   .Navigate<BarViewModel, DataParameter>(parameter);
```

and catch the data in following method:

```
public override Task Initialize(DataParameter parameter)
{
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Updating the answer from Denis Gordin, since MvvmCross 6, you should use `Prepare` method in the class you navigate to.

```
public override void Prepare(DataParameter parameter)
{
}
```